# How to customize Jira api with custom field values : jql starts with operator

Tags: python, python-requests, jira, jira-rest-api, jql

I'm using the python rest api to fetch data from the Jira API.

When I filter my URL call using a standard field (ie. issuetype='Story'), I have no issues.
URL : [https://example.com/rest/api/2/search?maxResults=500&jql=issuetype='Story'](https://example.com/rest/api/2/search?maxResults=500&jql=issuetype=%27Story%27)

However, I'm having issues filtering to a custom field that **starts with** 'P00'. I kept getting a 400 response code. I know field cf[10025] exists, but I'm having issues filtering to values that start with *P000xxxxx*

url: [https://example.com/rest/api/2/search?maxResults=500&jql=cf[10025]='~P000xxxxx'&fields=id,key,issuetype,status,customfield_10025](https://example.com/rest/api/2/search?maxResults=500&jql=cf%5B10025%5D=%27%7EP000xxxxx%27&fields=id,key,issuetype,status,customfield_10025)

Comment: Provide some code if possible. This is all way too broad to be able to figure out anything.

Comment: hi @KZiovas, this is more of an error on jql URL customization and less on overall code

Comment: Could you please provide more info on the configuration of the custom field? Use of the ~ operator only works with specific fields (I believe only system fields). And I don't believe it can be used within quotation marks.